# Firefox ESR release is dropping NPAPI support end actually drop?

Tags: firefox, release, npapi

When does NPAPI support end for the Firefox ESR releases?  I was unable to locate the answer on the Mozilla forums, and Google.

Answer (score 3):

The long-time projected date for the end of NPAPI support in Firefox is "[by the end of 2016](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)", which would mean Firefox 50 or 51.

According to Mozilla's [Firefox ESR roadmap](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/), this in turn means ESR would loose NAPI support when it's resynch'ed to Firefox 52, by March 2017.

But [developper input on the mozilla.dev.tech.plugins mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/mozilla.dev.tech.plugins/Cu1rOVEn45M/FYHz_XIoAAAJ) indicate that the removal in FF will actually happen a little later, in release 53, and that one reason for delaying the removal is indeed to bring extended support (**until May 2018**) through FF ESR, for those users who desperately need NPAPI support.

[Ghacks has a pretty good article on this topic](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/04/11/firefox-drm-and-the-end-of-npapi/).